# Having trouble pivoting a table of survey data

Tags: python, pivot

I'm using the "LGBT_Survey_DailyLife.csv" dataset from Kaggle([Link](https://www.kaggle.com/ruslankl/european-union-lgbt-survey-2012#LGBT_Survey_DailyLife.csv)) without the question_code and notes columns.

I want each question (question_label) and country (CountryCode) combination to be on its own line, and to have each column be a combination of group (subset) and response (answer) with the values being those given in the percentage column.

It seems like this should be pretty straightforward, but when I run the following:

```py
daily_life.pivot(index = ['CountryCode', 'question_label'], columns = ['subset', 'answer'], values = 'percentage')*
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Length of passed values is 34020, index implies 2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first clean up the `percentage` column as it contains non integer values
And then use `pivot_table`

```py
df.percentage = df.percentage.replace(':', 0).astype('float')

df1 = df.pivot_table(values="percentage", index=["CountryCode", "question_label"], columns=["subset", "answer"])
```